# Django: Запретить объектам класса Категория (модель) принимать в parent_categories (ManyToMany) самого себя

Tags: python, django

Как запретить категориям принимать в parent_categories самого себя? Лучше ли сделать поле "NoParentCategory" или же в filter проставить сравнение с (чем?), чтобы найти самые верхние категории.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_categories = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="subcategories", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить обработчик сигнала для ManyToMany (m2m_changed, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) который проверит, добавляет ли объект сам себя, учитывайте, что pk_set это множество id объектов добавляемых методом add или set. В данном случае action "pre_add" указывает на то что обработка будет совершена до внесения изменений в базу данных

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    parent_categories = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="subcategories", blank=True)


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Category.parent_categories.through)
def prevent_duplicate_tags_from_group(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'pre_add':
        if instance.pk in pk_set:
            raise ValidationError({'parent_categories': 'Cant add yourself'})
```